# the complexity of fibonacci trees algorithms

Tags: algorithm

Can I find the complexity of this algorithm:

```
if (n=1)
  T(n)=1
else if (n=2)
  T(n)=2
else 
  T(n)= 1+T(n-1)+2T(n-2)
```

this algorithm can be like this form

```
T(1)=1
T(2)=2
T(n)=1+T(n-1)+2T(n-2)
```

I hope to find the answer quickly ..

Comment: ... Is this homework?  Also, although stating the problem in a recursive format is more natural, it's a terrible way to actually calculate it on-the-fly.  And if this is for calculating fibonacci _numbers_, your formula has (a couple of) errors...

Answer (score 1):

There are standard techniques for solving a linear recurrence like that, but we can also use mathematica:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=T%28n%29+%3D+1+%2B+T%28n-1%29+%2B+2+T%28n-2%29+and+T%281%29+%3D+1+and+T%282%29+%3D+2